# django-wkhtmltopdf gives "[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, wkhtmltopdf

## urls.py

```
from wkhtmltopdf.views import PDFTemplateView
url(r'^pdf/$', PDFTemplateView.as_view(template_name='base/template.html',
            filename='template.pdf', 
            header_template='base/header.html', 
            footer_template='base/header.html', 
            ), name='pdf')
```

cmd is configured  in my settings.py file as shown below

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wkhtmltopdf"
```

I still get the same error

## solved

This issue was solved
by replacing forward slashes with backward slashes in path as shown below

```
WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD = "C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf"
```

Now i get a new error "[Error 5] Access is denied"

Comment: I stuck on the same place. I mean, my installation was on Windows, not in Python package, but I followed your solution and now I also get Access is denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the WKHTMLTOPDF_CMD should point to the wkhtmlpdf.exe binary which is a separate install from the wkhtmltopdf python package.

download the binary at [their website](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

Comment: might mean that the binary arent executable or that its in a place the www server user cannot read

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was wkhtmltopdf was located /usr/bin/ but my settings had some other location. Also make sure you have the permissions to the folder where the html is stored..